# How do I seed data into new columns in an existing Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I have a rails model called County that has 5 columns of data for different population attributes for that county. There is a record in the `counties` table for each county in the US. I now need to add additional county level data to meet a new need. The counties table will get an additional 10 or so rows for numeric population data (breakdown by race and ethnicity). I currently have the data in a .csv file, ready to go.

How do I seed the new data into the existing model such that I fill in the county specific information for each county in the database? Can this be done with `rake db:seed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you can use [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) to parse your input file. From there if you have a specific question please ask.

Comment: I would like to know how to handle this type of task most effectively. Should I just write a method in the model that I call to parse and loop through the .csv file and save each value into the proper field? Or is this something that can/should be handled through the `rake db:seed` task? I've done large seedings before using the rake task, but those were all with new models.

Comment: I would do it with a rake task, but not db:seed. Just a one-off custom task that loads in the new data. This is a one-time thing, right? It seemed that way from your question.